# How to speed up jaro-winkler process in python (multithread? pyspark?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyspark, multiprocessing

I am using jaro-winkler to do scoring for text similarity in python 3. My comparing set is relatively large (>470,000 rows). So each time, the loop need to calculate score for each strings with those 470,000 items, which made my process very slow.

Is there anyway I can speed up the process? I am thinking to use multithread, multiprocessing, or pyspark.  But I am not sure how to do so. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have been able to make it work for a smaller set? Like 100 rows?

Comment: that will decrease the accuracy I feel...

Comment: yes it will, but you will know it works before optimizing it.